# I can't get my array to print alphabetically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript.
I'm trying to get my array to print alphabetically but all the ways i have tried don't seem to work. eg array.sort(). 
Note that console.log doesn't print either for some reason unknown to me. 
Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   
<p id="products"></p>
<script>                            
var products =    ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Monitor","Keyboard","Mouse","Webcam","Hard Drive"];
document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = products; 
array.sort("products");
</script>
</body>
```

Many Thanks
Ted

Comment: try sorting it _before_ you add it to the page...

Comment: Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Also, there is no console.log in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.sort()` on your array in your case its the variable `products`. [**Array Sort**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

```js
var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Monitor","Keyboard","Mouse","Webcam","Hard Drive"];

products.sort(); // add this line

document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = products;
```

```html
<p id="products"></p>
```

Comment: @T.ROS glad to help, If this helped you resolve your issue then you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead
`document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = products.sort();`

Answer (score 1):

*sort()* is an extension method, and you don't need to pass the parameter to. You just need to call the array name with the function name. You can see more information about the sort() function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
var products =    ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Monitor","Keyboard","Mouse","Webcam","Hard Drive"];
products.sort();
document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = products;
```

```html
<p id="products"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `products.sort();`. Array has in-build feature to sort.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var products = ["Printer","Tablet","Router","Monitor","Keyboard","Mouse","Webcam","Hard Drive"];

products.sort(); // add this line

document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = products;
```

```html
<p id="products"></p>
```